# What is the use of Disaster Recovery Planning?

Tags: disaster-recovery

Im curious about Disaster Recovery Planning on what are they uses and how to use it in a proper way. Could someone help me or share there knowledge about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apologies, but I've voted to close this as it is outside the scope of running a website/mail.

Comment: Please do not add third-party links to questions, and only use one account here.

Answer (score 2):

A DRP is about planning and conducting exercises to ensure that your company can withstand a catastrophic event, and remain operational.

They typically are meant for testing IT resilience.

Some companies, for example banks, have rigorous DRP standards that need to be followed in order to stay compliant.

Some of these standards may include:

- Having full server redundancy for all their Tier1 applications
- Having a redundant datacenter at least 20 Km / 12 Miles apart from each other
- Conduct a DRP switchover in which you power down apps in your primary datacenter and start working at your backup/alternate/redundant datacenter for some time
- Conduct a DRP testing at least once per year
- Have an RTO (Return to Operation) for all their Tier1 applications in under X hours

Many companies over the years have gained immense knowledge of their core systems and IT resilience while conducting these exercises, as it forces you to do things that are not part of your business as usual.

Common things that I've experienced during DRP exercises are:

- Inability to restart applications
- Unexpected database crashes
- Sync failures
- Discovering that your backup strategy was flawed, because most backups were corrupt and nobody noticed until you needed to restore a particular file or server
- Communication failures between the primary and alternate datacenters

In general, a DRP is a healthy practice for an IT Department to test that they are prepared for a worst case scenario. Also, some big companies that will only work with yours, if you can attest that you conduct these kinds of testing at least annually.